# How to get the zero address from ecrecover?

Tags: cryptography, ecrecover

I have a fair understanding of how `ecrecover` works, but I don't know how to enforce a parameter set that will deterministically return the `0x0` address. I need this in my contract tests.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stumbled upon this [thread](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/681), then I discovered this [document](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d) and I now understand that setting `v` as any (positive?) number other than 27 or 28 will deterministically return `0x0` as the origin signer address.

Test it for yourself in solidity:

```
function getSignerZero(bytes32 msgHash, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public returns (address _signer) {
    uint8 wrongV = 17; // should normally be 27 or 28
    return ecrecover(msgHash, wrongV, r, s);
}
```

Also, a caveat if you're using assembly and `staticcall`: it's actually incorrect to say that the value **returned** is 0x0. What happens there is that the precompile never gets back with a new value, so your program will just point to the same value it pointed before the call.